# Can I use VestaCP with NGINX?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, panel, vesta

I want to host website using **VestaCP** with **nginx + php + mysql**. Is it possible? If anyone knows about it, please let me know. Thanx!

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

Comment: A crazy and controversial idea, how about [reading the documentation](https://vestacp.com/docs/)? Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you ... In the future I will do proper research and write down questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can. It requires fresh install of ubuntu.

> For a smooth installation you will need clean system "minimal install base"

Just follow their documentation and all should be ok.

https://vestacp.com/install/
OR https://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-install-vesta